# How do I get Linux to execute data on the stack?

Tags: buffer-overflow, penetration-testing, stack-smash

I have a Core i7 720QM processor and am running Slackware 13.37 (32-bit) as a virtual machine. As a class assignment, I have to write a vulnerable program and smash the stack. However, on most computers this does not work as there is some kind of stack execution prevention (NX bit?) this generates a 'segmentation fault' when the CPU detects an attempt to execute data on the stack.

Is there a way to signal the kernel via `sysctl` or something similar to ignore this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo apt-get install execstac
```

Should install [execstack](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/administration_systeme/execstack), a program that modifies ELF headers to enable/disable NX protection on the stack in target binaries.

```
$ execstack -s vuln
```

should make the stack executable for your example program.

Answer (score 1):

compile your program like this

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack <sourcefile> -o <outputfile>
```